# Confluence open source / example apps that integrate with Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

I am considering creating a custom Confluence app that displays information from Jira.

Are there examples or open source projects for me to take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can display Jira information using Jira macro. To do this simply type in
{ JIRA

this will automatically open the Jira macro. In this macro you can create a search query from your Jira and insert it here. You will also have to select the right Jira cluster. Another good feature about this tool is that you can also create pie chart from your Jira query. You can customize the pie chart using different Jira fields.